# Keep getting 'cursor is READ-ONLY'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, database-cursor

My code seems pretty forward.

I want to update a specific field with a unique counter, not equal {1,2,3,...}.

I keep getting the error 'The cursor is READ ONLY.'

Also: is there a simpler way?

```
declare @MaxVal int = NULL
declare @fetchVal int = NULL
select @MaxVal = MAX(tp_Id)+1 from [<tableContainingInitialMaxval>] 
/** some default **/

DECLARE curs01 CURSOR 
for select @maxVal + row_number() OVER (order by [<someUniqueField>]) from [<table2update>];
(used FOR UPDATE OF [<field2update>] but that made no difference)

open curs01
FETCH NEXT FROM curs01 INTO @fetchVal;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        update [<table2update>] set [<field2update>] =  @fetchVal 
        WHERE CURRENT OF curs01;
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs01 INTO @fetchVal;
    end;
CLOSE curs01;
DEALLOCATE curs01;
GO
```

Comment: FWIW, there is no SQL Server 8. Most recent versions are 6.5, 7.0, 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012.

Comment: Sorry, it was 2008 R2 to be more percise

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this.

```
DECLARE @MaxVal INT = NULL

SELECT @MaxVal = MAX(tp_Id) + 1
FROM   tableContainingInitialMaxval;

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                @maxVal + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY someUniqueField) AS rn
         FROM   table2update)
UPDATE CTE
SET    field2update = rn
```